# Is video more effective than traditional text help?

Tags: text, help, video, documentation

Does anyone have experience with users' success or failure in using video or "task recording", as opposed to traditional textual help to complete their task or get more information?

Additionally, what is the impact on accessibility?

Comment: Same question here with a target audience of service technicians. Would service technicians tend/prefer to read servicing documentation or watch servicing videos? Would their tendency change over time with experience? Are there any kind of studies on this subject?

Answer (score 2):

My experience, in writing up much documentation and creating video content, is it depends. Some things require no more than a basic list of text instructions. Others are more nuanced and require video to be more effective. Different types of people also have their preference.

A good example is video game walkthroughs. If you get stuck on a certain part of a game, you can read text that tells you what to do, but I've rarely succeeded because of that. One quick video and done: I get it.

Give me a set of instructions on how to adjust registry files on a PC? Video is just going to slow me down. The static display with the easy ability to take one piece of data at a time to act on provides for a better experience.

So to answer the question based on your case, ask the following: what does the end user need to learn with this data and do they need to retain it?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Instructions not task. Maybe this may help you.

http://www.academia.edu/3587345/_The_Usability_of_Print_and_Online_Video_Instructions_